# How to Prove or disprove $(1-z)(1-y)(1-x) \ge 8xyz$

Tags: inequality

How many sententes are true?　($x,y,z \ge 0$)

1.　$(x+y)(y+z)(z+x) \ge 8xyz$

2.　$(1-z)(1-y)(1-x) \ge 8xyz$

> 1.　$\displaystyle 1$
>
> 2.　$\displaystyle 2$
>
> 3.　None of them
>
> 4.　Both of them

**My attempt**:I have proved the first one like this:

$\left.
\begin{array}{l}
\ x+y \ge 2\sqrt{xy} \\
\ y+z \ge 2\sqrt{yz}\\
\ z+x \ge 2\sqrt{zx}
\end{array}
\right\}
\Rightarrow (x+y)(y+z)(z+x) \ge 8xyz$

But I can't prove or disprove the second one.

Comment: Do we have some sort of constraints on $x,y,z$ such as $x+y+z = 1$?

Comment: By the given information, Statement $2$ is false for $x=1,y=1,z=1$

Comment: You need some more information. For example, statement two is false if you have $x = 1$ or something similar.

Comment: Ok then it is false thanks.

Comment: You mean $x+y\geq 2\sqrt{xy}$, etc., right?

Comment: If $x+y+z=1$, statement 2 is true.

Comment: @TakahiroWaki Yes then it gives the same thing as the first one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first one, just expand the whole product, and you will get:

$$x^2(y + z) + y^2(x + z) + z^2(x + y) \geq 6xyz$$

Now since $x, y, z, \geq 0$ you have, by definition, that $x+y$ and related sums are positive. 
The squares are positive by definition and in the most simple case, namely $x = y = z = 1$ you would obtain:

$$6 \geq 6$$

which holds true.

The trivial case, $x = y = z = 0$ holds true too but it's trivial.

So number $1$ holds.

Number $2$ doesn't hold, and the simplest proof is setting $x =  1$, or $y = 1$ and so on.

You can easily see that it holds even if you choose non natural numbers, even if you set things like $x = 1/2$, $y = 1/3$ $z = 1/4$

Comment: I managed to manipulate the inequality to $x^2(y + z) + y^2(x + z) + z^2(x + y) \geq 6xyz$. But I struuggled to use Trival Inequality or the AM-GM Inequality to show the early inequality holds. Can we do this? The OP attempt dosen't feel right.